# How Do I Get the Most Popular Zip Codes in my Customer Table in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been fighting with this one for a little while. This gets me all of the counts for each zip code...

```
Customer.group(:zip).count
```

But I can't get it to order by the ones with the highest count. Seems like this should be simple but I can't seem to find anything that addresses this case.

UPDATE: Getting the most popular cities and states would probably be even more helpful. It seems to me ActiveRecord really isn't suited for this, as i'm not really asking for a Cutomer model, but I can't find anything about querying outside of ActiveRecord. If anyone can point me to any resources about interacting with the database in cases where I don't need the data to fit into a model object, that would be very helpful.

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html is one option or https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try follow syntax, it will return result with the highest count:

```
Customer.group(:zip).order("count_zip desc").count(:zip)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want. you can 
try any of the following below

```
Customer.where(zip: 'testcode').maximum("value")
```

or you could try this

```
Customer.where(zip: 'testcode').order("value DESC").first
```

or

```
Customer.where(zip: :testcode).order(value: :desc).first
```

you also have ruby documentation at your rescue
[link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations)